# Hacer una copia de un Observable sin que se vea afectada al modificar el Observable

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs

Estoy consumiendo un servicio, el cual me regresa un observable al que luego me suscribo. Quiero hacerle una copia a una variable, a la cual le asigno la respuesta del observable, pero cuando modifico la variable inicial, los cambios se aplican a la copia también.

El servicio es el siguiente:

```js
this.service.getdepartamentos().subscribe(res => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res.items)
this.dataSourceCopia = this.dataSource

/*También lo intenté con 
    this.dataSourceCopia = res.items
*/
    }
```

El dataSource lo modifico así

```html
<td class="border" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
   <input matInput value="{{element.cod_marcadodepart_}}" 
   (change)="element.cod_marcadodepart_ = $event.target.value">
</td>
```

Pero cuando imprimo por consola las dos variables (dataSource y dataSourceCopy), resulta que los dos fueron modificados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: this.dataSourceCopia = new MatTableDataSource(res.items)

Comment: @AdrianGodoy Sigue sin funcionar. 
Lo intenté pero cuando modifico dataSource, también se modifica dataSourceCopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto no tiene nada que ver con los observables.

El problema es que los objetos y los arrays mantienen la referencia en javascript.

por lo tanto al tener un objeto si después lo asignas a otro y cambias algo en alguno de los dos te va a cambiar en los dos sitios.

ejemplo:

```
const hola1 = {x: 1};
const hola2 = hola1;

hola2.x = 4;

console.log(hola1); // {x:4}
```

Para solucionar esto hay muchas librerías pero te recomiendo la de [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)

y usa el método "cloneDeep".

ejemplo:

```
const hola1 = {x: 1};
const hola2 = _.cloneDeep(hola1);

hola2.x = 4

console.log(hola1); // {x: 1}
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente lo que quieres pero puedes usar un array
algo parecido

```
dataSource = []
```

y en el metodo

```
this.dataSource[this.dataSource.length] = new MatTableDataSource(res.items)
this.dataSourceCopia = this.dataSource[this.dataSource.length -1]
```

de esta forma creas una array multidimensional con todos los valores del observable

Comment: La respuesta del servidor se la asigno a dataSource. Quiero tener la copia de esa respuesta para compararla luego con el dataSource final, es decir, modificado. Y así ver qué cambios fueron realizados y poder hacer un PUT a la DB y no hacer el PUT con todos los registros así no hayan sido modificados. Por eso es que quiero hacer la copia del res.items. Pero solo modifico el dataSource y automáticamente se me modifica la copia.